# Is there a way to dump loaded scripts from a webpage via a commandline?

Tags: linux, bash, web

Rather than viewing/dumping the a webpage source, I'm wanting to have a page render and dump the url's being loaded by a site? (via a command line).

So if I visit google.com for example.

`https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png`
`https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/i1_1967ca6a.png`
`https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/googlemic/2x/googlemic_color_24dp.png`
`https://www.google.com/images/searchbox/desktop_searchbox_sprites302_hr.webp`
`...`

Is this possible?

Comment: You want to download those files, or just display the urls?

Comment: Try `lynx -dump -listonly www.google.com`

Comment: @Shawn just list everything being loaded

Comment: @MarkSetchell those are just links, and not loaded content from lynx?